# Standard SQLStates in an enum

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'd like to have an enum containing all standard SQLStates so I can:

1. Respond to expected SQL failures programmatically. For example, I want to retry operations that fail due to race conditions. For example, one thread removes a row referenced by another thread, or two threads attempt to insert the same record thereby triggering a UNIQUE constraint violation.
2. Look up the meaning of an error very quickly. There doesn't seem to be an all-inclusive document on SQLStates, least of all their meaning.

Comment: The [`java.sql.SQLException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) contains all the data you need for handling these exceptions. Note that the SQL code will vary depending on the RDBMS.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Sorry for that. This post was meant to be a contribution to the community. I didn't realize the question would become visible before the answer.

Comment: I personally find the utility mentioned in the answer useful (even if it's kind of self-promotion). Voted to re-open the question. _P.S._ The utility is in the Maven central, so it would be helpful to mention the dependency: `org.bitbucket.cowwoc:sqlstate:1.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a long time to compile this information. I hope this helps others. [Source code on Bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/sqlstate/src/f6c8d60d3aea5776263dc4f18914dec15c01e109/src/main/java/org/bitbucket/cowwoc/sqlstate/SQLState.java?at=default)

**Contributions are welcome!**

(I couldn't post the source-code on Stackoverflow because it is bigger than 30,000 characters)

Comment: In your `fromCode` methods you throw `IllegalArgumentException` if no matching enum is found. Databases are by specification allowed to use additional SQLstates (both as subcodes in existing categories, or in vendor-specific categories), as such I wouldn't consider it an exceptional condition.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Can you provide a source? Where can I find this in the specification?

Comment: In ISO/IEC 9075-2:2011 (aka SQL 2011 Foundation), chapter 24, "Status codes"; note that other 'books' of the standard define additional codes than those listed in the accompanying table (eg the PSM book (ISO/IEC 9075-4:2011) and also the CLI book (ISO/IEC 9075-3:2003; not sure if CLI was updated in 2011) lists additional codes)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks for the feedback. I've committed an update that adds an IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC enum constant.